# How can I get Distinct Count in Pivot in Mac Excel?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a data set of 40,000 rows and I am looking to find count of distinct values for a specific column within the data set. I know Excel for Mac doesn't support data model. Has anyone found an alternate way to do this via formulas? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the helper column to calculate the part of total items count in a group that can be summed in the pivot table.

For example, to get count of distinct names in group I divide 1 by total count of names in group

```
=1/SUMPRODUCT((A2=$A$2:$A$16)*(B2=$B$2:$B$16))
```

and in pivot table I can sum all parts.

[image]